# Ipod Camera Scan for similar color

Tags: ios

i was working on building an application that would dynamically assign shapes, for example a circle, on walls, or similar objects, based on the cameras output,  i had the idea that i could use the pixel data from the cameras raw output, and then compare the colors to find things that are similar in color, and then find walls based from that, but i feel there must be a better way to do this, any suggestions?
along the sames lines, i also need to find the depth of the objects, to find the distance from the ipod that the objects are, is there anywhere to look to find that data?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not do it and you will have to dive a lot deeper into this subject to get something done yourself. However, there are others that have done the hard part for you already; have a look at [Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/search/apachesolr_search/qdevnet%20sdk%20ios#per-page=50&ft=forum).

Comment: when using the vufloria sdk, do you have to give vufloria a percentage of your app sales?  i cant seem to find what using their sdk entails as far as development goes

Comment: For details on the licensing, please see https://developer.vuforia.com/legal/license - but to make it short, Qualcomm does not demand a share of your app.